# Design generator stator for maximum power at low speeds

Tags: power, low-power, generator

I am building a very small fluid turbine & AC generator. It is a radial flux permanent magnet machine. It's about a few cm sphere/cylinder. I'm wondering what tips you have for optimizing the coils.

An illustrative cross-section of the setup to ease visualization:
[image: Cross-section]

Another illustration. Not my product, but the same concept, "rim driven turbine".
[image: Illustration]

To give some numbers, I want to extract at least 300 mV and 1 mW of power at as low speeds/torques as possible. As soon as I overcome static mechanical friction I'm at about 30 Hz on the electrical signal with my current design. At the onset of rotation, I think that the breaking mechanical forces are much bigger than the emf torque, that's why I write speed/torque.

Some design parameters are obviously beneficial. Smaller air gap => more induction. But what about the more ambiguous parameters?
I'm thinking I should use thin wires to get many turns, does that make sense? Why (Maxwell)?
Wireless charging uses thick wires and few turns...
Is it worth sacrificing valuable radial space for the ferrite? (every mm that's ferrite could have been bigger stator coils, bigger magnets or a bigger rotor)?

I've been winding air-core coils (for no cogging, but I think that's optimizing the wrong thing) with thin magnetic wire. But I can buy PCB SMD inductors with higher inductance for the same size. And with higher series resistance. Should I?

What are good rules of thumb or lessons from experience for generators? Any good reading tips?

Comment: I have seen such small generators in shower heads with LED illumination. You could get some ideas from their construction.

Comment: Need more information; please _edit your question_.  A picture or a 3D model of your current arrangement would be helpful.  You mention a "yoke", but I think perhaps you mean an iron or ferrite _armature_ that's part of the magnetic path?  Have you considered using a small model airplane brushless motor and installing it into an appropriate housing?  DC electric machines are two-way transducers; a motor isn't the most efficient possible setup for generating, but it comes pretty close.

Comment: @TimWescott I added another picture. And the term "rim driven turbine" if anyone wants to search for more.
Perhaps "yoke" was not quite correct. I changed it to simply "Ferrite".

I can't use an airplane motor because
1. They are not rim driven, the motor is separate from the propeller
2. They are DC, I have AC.
3. They are optimized for high thrust, which I'm pretty sure is quite the opposite to what I'm looking for (but that's really my question).

Comment: 1mW is a ridiculously tiny amount of power. What diameter is this thing? Do you care at all about mechanical->electrical conversion efficiency?

Comment: @Jon I know. And yes, getting to 1 mW for as small rotation speeds as possible is what I am asking about. What coils should I use for that?

No, mechanical->electrical efficiency is not important. A few % is all I can hope for. Perhaps a bit more.

As stated, the overall size is <5 cm, very limited.

Comment: Consider a claw pole construction. Consider electrical steel instead of ferrite. `300 mV and 1 mW of power` would 2- or 3-phase do? Try reluctance machines, too.

Comment: @greybeard Why claw pole? Do you have a good reading tip?

Yes, other materials are better, but the small size makes it awkward to stack stator plates. Perhaps I should look again at the material I'm using though, thanks.

Any number of phases really. What do you think would generate 1mW @ 0.3V earliest? I'm thinking classic 3 phase. I'm not sure on how to select number of poles though, any tips?

Reluctance is great for motors, but a big awkward for generators due to excitement. Especially for small devices like mine. I can't really fit an excitation device.

Comment: I'd look for a low power motor with a very low no load current and a somewhat high voltage (low \$k_v\$) and start experimenting with that - if brushed, you can pick segments of the commutator to connect to, and pull the (spring loaded)  brushes off the segments or remove them. Note that while you may want a low torque ripple, you seem to be at liberty with regard to electrical wave forms.

Comment: (Out of curiosity: What use do you put 300mV 1mW AC to?)

Comment: My fluid is liquid, not gas, and prototypes show that yes it is quite possible to reach the amounts I'm looking for. This question was more on how to optimize.
I use the energy to feed this harvester, from there the possibilities are endless. https://e-peas.com/product/aem30940/